# Python find value in text string

Tags: python, regex, automation, network-programming, pattern-matching

I am building a network automation script in python, and I got into a problem that I don't know how to resolve. I have the following output

```
CPE-MGT {
    instance-type virtual-router;
    interface ge-0/0/0.0;
    routing-options {
        static {
            route 192.168.253.115/32 next-hop 192.168.100.1;
            route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 192.168.100.1;
        }
    }
}
DATA {
    instance-type virtual-router;
    interface ge-0/0/1.0;
}
MGMT_BK {
    instance-type virtual-router;
    interface ge-0/0/2.0;
    routing-options {
        static {
            route 192.168.253.115/32 next-hop 192.168.100.1;
            route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 192.168.100.1;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to obtain the name of there I find the name of specific primary key interfaces; perhaps it will be clearer if I give an example.

I have a regex that looks into the text and finds that ge-0/0/0.0 is in the text now; what I don't know is how to obtain CPE-MGT.

````
cmd = net_connect.send_command(
        juniper_cmds["sh_routing_instance"])
    logger.debug(f'{ip_dict[config_dict["csv_ip_colum"]][ips]}:Device routing instances {cmd}')
    regex_routing_instance = re.compile(f'{interface[0]}')
    routing_instance = regex_routing_instance.findall(cmd)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two patterns and the `regex` module which offers recursion:

```
import regex as re

data = """
CPE-MGT {
    instance-type virtual-router;
    interface ge-0/0/0.0;
    routing-options {
        static {
            route 192.168.253.115/32 next-hop 192.168.100.1;
            route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 192.168.100.1;
        }
    }
}
DATA {
    instance-type virtual-router;
    interface ge-0/0/1.0;
}
MGMT_BK {
    instance-type virtual-router;
    interface ge-0/0/2.0;
    routing-options {
        static {
            route 192.168.253.115/32 next-hop 192.168.100.1;
            route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 192.168.100.1;
        }
    }
}
"""

rx_block = re.compile(r"""
    ^(?P<name>[A-Z_-]+)\s+
    (?P<body>\{
        (?:(?:[^{}]+)|(?2))+
    \})
""", re.M | re.X)

rx_inner = re.compile(r"interface ge-0/0/0.0;")

for block in rx_block.finditer(data):
    m = rx_inner.search(block.group('body'))
    if m:
        print(block.group('name'))
```

---

This would yield

```
CPE-MGT
```

Two notes here: you wouldn't really need a regular expression for the inner search as it is a static string and two - probably use a parser solution instead.
See [**a demo for the expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/coUhw1/1).

Comment: Thank you! When I move it to python, it fails in regex101. I am trying to figure out why

Comment: Because the normal regex module (re) does not support recursion.

Comment: My bad I didn't see the import on the top. Thanks a lot for your help